# How can I do one cross-program-invocation with multiple instructions?

Tags: cpi, program, transfer, transaction, instruction

in a nutshell I'm wondering how to send one CPI call with a vector of Instructions.

**Here's an example:**

I noticed there's a function in the `solana_program` Rust crate called:

```
solana_program::system_instruction::transfer_many
```

It's parameters & return type are as follows:

```
pub fn transfer_many(
    from_pubkey: &Pubkey,
    to_lamports: &[(Pubkey, u64)]
) -> Vec<Instruction>
```

This will obviously return to me a vector of Instruction types, but as far as I can tell `invoke` and `invoke_signed` are designed for one instruction at a time.

How can I use this vector of instructions dynamically, say if I want my program to transfer 3 different amounts to 3 different accounts in one transaction?

One can infer that you could iterate over the vector and use `invoke`, but that raises three concerns:

1. This seems sort of strange.
2. How do I determine, for each `invoke` call, what accounts to pass?
3. How do I determine, for each `invoke_signed` call, what seeds to sign with?

Is there some way to do a single CPI that will send a transaction with multiple instructions?

Link to function: https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/system_instruction/fn.transfer_many.html

Answer (score 1):

Invoke and invoke_signed only execute a single ix per execution.

TransferMany does this:

```
pub fn transfer_many(from_pubkey: &Pubkey, to_lamports: &[(Pubkey, u64)]) -> Vec<Instruction> {
    to_lamports
        .iter()
        .map(|(to_pubkey, lamports)| transfer(from_pubkey, to_pubkey, *lamports))
        .collect() }
```

So the elements will in order contain the result of
`solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(from_pubkey, to_pubkey, lamports)`

which means the seeds will always be the signer/sender seeds, and accounts will be the corresponding [from_pubkey, to_pubkey] accountInfos.